# Can the sum of three constants be zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have three constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ and none of $A$, $B$ or $C$ are equal to $0$. Is it possible that the sum of these three constants is $0$? That is, is this possible:
$$A+B+C=0?$$

I am asking this question because I want to know that if constants can have a negative value.

Because the only way $A+B+C$ is zero, is for any one or two of the three constants to have a negative value.

Comment: `Because the only way (A+B+C) is zero, is for any one or two of the three constants to have a negative value.` Not necessarily, they could all be $0$, or be complex numbers for that matter. It helped your question if you defined what you mean by "*constant*".

Comment: @dxiv No I actually said at the top, " none of A, B or C is equal to zero"

Comment: Let $A=1, B= \omega, C=\omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity, then $\,A+B+C=0\,$ and none of them is zero or negative (because non-real complex numbers have no sign). Again, define "*constant*".

Comment: If three nonzero reals add to zero, at least one is positive, and at least one is negative.

Comment: "*Can the sum of three constants be zero*"  Yes: $(-1)+(-2)+(3)=0$,  $(i-1)+(-i)+(1)=0$, among others.

Comment: This is what i've tried with a+b+c=0. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818895/computing-for-rsa-numbers-with-ab-c-or-abc-0?noredirect=1#comment5813787_2818895

Comment: "I want to know that if constants can have a negative value."  Why the heck couldn't they be negative?

Comment: " is for any one or two of the three constants to have a negative value."  There is nothing at all ususual or strange about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I have three constants A, B and C and none of A, B or C is equal to 0. Is it possible that the sum of these three constants is 0?

Sure,  That would happen whenever $A = -B-C$ (which would mean $B = -A -C$ and $C = - A-B$.

> That is, is this possible:
>   A+B+C=0?

Sure, $A = 2; B=-7$ and $C = -2 + 7 = 5$, is just one example.

> I am asking this question because I want to know that if constants can have a negative value.

Well, of course they can.  Why on earth would you think that wouldn't be allowed for some reason?

I feel there must be more to the question than you are asking. It seems a very bizarre thing to think that constants can't be negative.  Why wouldn't you assume constants can be any number and numbers can be negative?

> Because the only way A+B+C is zero, is for any one or two of the three constants to have a negative value.

That's true if $A,B,C$ are all real.  If you allow complex numbers complex numbers do need to be positive or negative so none of the have to be.  But you must have $C= -A -B$.  But if $A$ and $B$ are neither positive nor negative complex then $C$ is neither positive nor negative complex.

Answer (score 2):

A constant may be natural number, integer, rational, real, vector, etc. If not explicitly stated what kind of numbers $A,B,C$ are, you should be able to determine from context which values are permitted.